# Assign address of number to a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int *n=(int *)5;//Valid
cout<<*n;//Invalid
```

Why pointer n can point to an address although 5 is not a memory location.
Why I can not print out the screen the value of n.

Comment: 5 is a memory location

Comment: 5 is a memory location but it do not store any data ???
If it store data, how to print it out ???

Comment: You are attempting to dereference a pointer that points to an invalid location.

Comment: For beginners, if you need to cast you are doing something wrong.  For experts, if you need to cast you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: ***but it do not store any data ???*** Likely not unless you are using an embedded system. With a modern operating system your process will have a virtual address space. And many such systems will avoid the addresses close to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to dereference memory address 0x5, which is probably restricted memory.

```
int *n=(int *)5;
```

You are casting the integer literal 5 as an `int*`. What that means is you are saying 0x5 is an address. When attempting to dereference that pointer with `*n`, you will get an error.

Instead, you would need to do something like:

```cpp
int five = 5;
int *n = &five;
cout << *n;
```

Don't use `(int *)`, use the address-of operator `&`. Also keep in mind you cannot take the address of a literal other than string literals.

Comment: @Quentin. Yeah. Nevermind. Dunno what I was thinking :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: because the value of `n` is `n`. `*n` is the value *at* `n`: i.e., what it's pointing to.

If you want `n` to point to the value 5 rather than the address 5, you have to make it do so:

```
int x = 5;
int* n = &x;
```

Now `n` is the address of a stack location that has 5 as its value.